# Kendo DateTimePicker returns a value of {01.01.0001 00:00:00}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datetimepicker

I have this Datetimepicker that has Value(DateTime.now).
If I don't select any date, the date that I get is {01.01.0001 00:00:00}.
Shouldn't I be getting the value that the datetimepicker shows on my page?
Is there a way to fix this? What I am doing wrong?
Tks in advance?

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
              .Name("scanningDate")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
              .Value(DateTime.Now)
              .WeekNumber(true)
              .Max(DateTime.Today)
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the DateTimePicker is null because you have configured the Max() to a value *smaller* than the Value() you are assigning to it.

i.e. you are setting the Value() to Now(2017-06-26 08:08:37) bu the Max is Today(2017-06-26 00:00:00).
So, the set Value exceeds the Max and the thus the current Value is null....despite what the visible portion of the control is telling your eyes.

You need to increase the Max() to at least exceed the initial Value you are trying to set it to.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting default value of **DateTime.MinValue** which is 01/01/0001 for ScanDate property of ViewModel.

Bind ScanDate Property to DatePicker Control so that you get **SelectedValue**
of the **DateTimePicker** into your **MVC Controller**.

Change code like:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.ScanDate)
              .Name("ScanDate")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
              .Value(DateTime.Now)
              .WeekNumber(true)
              .Max(DateTime.Today)
  )
```